# Authenticating and transferring CSV files from GCS to a remote network drive in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory, active-directory, google-cloud-storage

I'm wanting to use a containerised Python app to connect and authenticate to an AD managed network drive on a physical file server to then transfer some csv files to it from a Google Cloud bucket  and I'm wondering what the best options are to do this?

So far I have established that I can see the server using:

```py
    try:
        smbclient.register_session("xx.xx.xx.xx", username="user", password="pass")
    except Exception as exec:
        print(exec)
```

But this leads me to the problem of the best way to authenticate against it.  I'm unfortunately not a very experienced programmer, I was wondering if there was some sort of token exchange that I could implement?

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
mount_string = f'mount -t cifs -o username={secret_dict["user"]}, {secret_dict["password"]} //<serverip>/<share> {mount}'

try:
    os.system(mount_string)
except Exception as exec:
    print(exec)
```